# Как использовать json вместо csv в d3? Чарт как у gihub

Tags: javascript, github, диаграммы, d3.js

[image]

Хочу реализовать [этот](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063318) чарт , но не могу понять, как исопользовать json, а не csv.

С d3 практически не знаком =(

Модель данных следующая (у каждого объекта id, createdAt, numberOfWords fields):

```
{ 

    { 
    _id: someId, 
    createdAt: 05/31/2016, 
    numberOfWords: 0 < number < 1000
    },
     ..., 
    ... 
}
```

- Должен ли я поменять
  `d3.csv`
  на
  `d3.json`?
- Можно ли передовать в d3.json переменную, а не файл?
- Будут ли проблемы со цветовой гаммой?
- Как правильно поменять функцию, которая передается в rollup?

Comment: Вы же разработчики, вы должны знать язык хотя бы на среднем уровне. Иначе как вы переменные и функции создаете?))

Comment: Да, я тоже так подумал, но раз уж просят, то, наверное, смысл есть. Будем надеяться, что он есть)

Comment: @YanisUrbis, в виду того, что у нас есть и англоязычная ветка и русскоязычная имеет смысл на русской писать на русском. А так да - большинство тут англ знает (отвечающие так и вообще все знают). И вам, конечно, никто не мешает создавать одинаковые вопросы и на русском и на англ. на разных ветках сайта.